# GitHub не может определить пользователя при git push с консоли

Tags: git, консоль, github, pycharm, git-push

Собственно, вопрос в следующем:
Делаю какие-то действия в редакторе кода (PyCharm), после чего делаю commit. Настало время заливать - сталкиваюсь со следующей проблемой. Если пушить при помощи инструментария PyCharm, то GitHub определяет, кто сделал commit:
[image: При git push из PyCharm]

Если же я буду делать git push через консоль GNU\Linux или же Powershell (Просто проверял и там и там), то GitHub не определяет, кто сделал commit:
[image: При git push из консоли]

Cуть отличия тут в том, что в первом варианте - есть картинка профиля пользователя, а так же кликабильно имя пользователя. Во втором же случае - такого нет.

Comment: Проверяйте, что почта указана корректная.

Comment: Email схожий. Что в конфиге, что на GitHub. Хотя, у меня только что появилась мысль, что можно попробовать. Это использовать внутренний enail GitHub. Там прямо так и написано "...will be used for web-based Git operations..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
Оказывается, не достаточно совпадения почты, которую вы указываете через:

```bash
git config --global user.mail user@example.com
```

Для того, чтобы GitHub действительно понял, что вы - это вы, необходимо указать почту, которая используется GitHub как внутренний адрес. Т.е указать в config необходимо email следующей формы:

```bash
git config --global user.mail 111111111+User@users.noreply.github.com
```

Найти этот email можно в описании поля, перейдя в:

> Git-Hub -> settings -> emails -> primory email address

Спасибо @user7860670 за наводку.